# jQuery Поднять на сервер json / работа с json на сервере

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Проблема не в коде! На [этой ссылке](http://questionapi.esy.es/) мои json для тестa; мне не удается с jsona принять данные. Мне кажется что я неправильно поднимаю на сервер. Подскажите как правильно поднять на сервер json и принять данные c jsona.

Этим кодом я воспользовался но получил ошибку подсоединение к серверу. Конечно я изменил код в моих целях.

```
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не помешало бы ещё продемонстрировать полностью шаблон, который используется для вывода. Я попробовал повторить ваш код и у меня всё работает. [Вот пример рабочего кода](http://plnkr.co/edit/ygJlwLv4MXxCsEqg2u8X?p=preview)

Comment: да но линк  ихний попытайтесь вывести с этого линка http://questionapi.esy.es/ . любой json yмена работает проблема в том что я свой json пытаюсь поднять на сервер прочитать с него а не с чужова json !

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ .

Comment: вот это ихний json http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

Comment: При попытке запроса к http://questionapi.esy.es/ в консоли выходит ошибка **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://questionapi.esy.es/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.**. Необходимо настроить сервер http://questionapi.esy.es/ на кроссдоменные запросы. Вот статья на эту тему [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: Огромное спасибо